# this.userId is undefined after Meteor.loginWithFacebook

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

What am I missing? I have this publisher in `server` folder:

```
Meteor.publish("myBooks", () => {
    console.log(this.userId);
    return Books.find({
        owner: this.userId
    });
});
```

`this.userId` is always undefined, whether I'm logged in or not. I use `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` call (in the `client` folder) to log in with my profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the [fat arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for defining the function which ties `this` to the lexical scope, i.e. the *gloabal* scope, or the scope of the nearest parent function, in case of NodeJS. Since there probably isn't a `userId` defined in the parent scope, you are seeing `this.userId` to be `undefined`.

Use the `function` form to fix the context (i.e. `this`) in your code:

```
Meteor.publish("myBooks", function () {
    console.log(this.userId);
    return Books.find({
        owner: this.userId
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Still getting used to the semantics of ES6 syntax while learning Angular 2 and Meteor at the same time causes some odd issues. Time to take a more holistic apporach I guess.